# goa'uld FTL drive technology

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

What is the name of the FTL drive the goa'uld use that rivals hyper drive in its speed. Is it a completely different drive, or just a modified hyper drive.

Answer (score 6):

The [Stargate wikia](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Goa%27uld) just says their [ships](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Ha%27tak) use an Interstellar [Hyperdrive](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Hyperdrive#Goa.27uld).

> [Like most Goa'uld starships, Anubis's mothership contained a hyperdrive allowing for faster-than-light travel within the Milky Way galaxy.](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Anubis%27_mothership#Power_systems)

The wikia, at least, seems to make little distinction between the drives on the various Motherships and Ha'tak. The tech seems to be crossover.

Hyperdrives are complimented by [Inertial Dampeners](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Inertial_dampener#Goa.27uld) because travel at such high speeds would cause instantaneous death due to the sudden acceleration.

> All Goa'uld vessels are equipped with inertial dampeners. They are effective at any speeds, but cannot completely compensate for the activation or deactivation of the hyperdrive, **causing the unprepared to be thrown across the room** with a mild amount of force. (SG1: "Within the Serpent's Grasp")

I'm not sure how reliable this wikia is, but it does cite sources at the bottom of their pages referencing shows, RPG's and such. [Example](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Ha%27tak#References_and_notes).

Comment: Up until Stargate Universe, all FTL was either through a wormhole (mostly a Stargate) or hyperdrive.  SG:U introduced Destiny's normal-space FTL, and showed that even in other galaxies, the aliens there developed hyperdrive.  So +1 from me.

Comment: more information: it was in the episode when jack O'Neill and teal'c were taken hostage by klorel, and teal'c warns O'Neill about he deceleration.

Comment: @joshua Answer edited to address your comment.